# JNDI Nothing to bind for name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, jetty, jndi

I'm trying to deploy a war file using Jetty and MariaDB and I'm requested to use a docker-compose file.

This is my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
    MariaDB:
        image: mariadb
        restart: always
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: user
            MYSQL_DATABASE: devopsdblocal

    jetty:
        image: jetty
        depends_on: 
            - "MariaDB"
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - ./target/deploy.war:/var/lib/jetty/webapps/root.war
```

This is my **web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/devopsdblocal</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

My **jetty-env.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
 
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="project-db" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>jdbc/devopsdblocal</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
                <Set name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/</Set>
                <Set name="username">user</Set>
                <Set name="password">user</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

And this is from the source code that I received and can't change :

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
            dataSource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/devopsdblocal");
```

When I try to run docker-compose up, I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nothing to bind for name
> jdbc/devopsdblocal

I've been stuck on this for the whole day now and haven't been able to find any suitable answer..
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Quite sure you have to put a third <Arg> in your jndi.Resource, for example <Arg></Arg> . If it should be empty or no it depends by the scope you want to use, give a look to this https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.php looking for jndi keywords